# Turn off link hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass, bem

I am working with Bootstrap SASS and Bootstrap SASS Loader.

I am defining a `_bootstrap-customizations.scss` file that allows me to override BS default variables *without* changing it's core files.

The core files define some `a:hover, a:active` CSS declarations.

I would like to turn that off universally for all `a` elements *without*

- defining this explicitly on each link
- by name-spacing or whatever
- or using `!important`

**I'd like to turn** `a:hover`**effects *off* completely**(`from _bootstrap-customizations.scss`).

If it matters I'm using the BEM methodology as well for writing my SASS files

Comment: What's the question? It should be a matter of defining identical styles for static, hover, and active states.

Comment: @isherwood so what's gonna happen if my links are different colors throughout the site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass/Compass - Generate rule only if parameter is not default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432268/sass-compass-generate-rule-only-if-parameter-is-not-default)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should inherit the values from `a` on `a:hover` and `a:active`:

```
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: inherit;
}
```

That way, the hovers will have the same default style. Note that not every selector supports the `inherit` value.

Comment: inherit will take it from the parent - which is not what I need in my case